# JS action button disable using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

I have a shiny application where i need to disable the action buttons after one has been clicked to stop a user spamming buttons, i wrote some JS script to do this when the server is busy ("shiny:busy") and unlocks when the server is idol ("shiny:idle"). like so:

```
$(document).on("shiny:busy", function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
  console.log(inputs);
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
});

$(document).on("shiny:idle", function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
  console.log(inputs);
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = false;
}
});
```

Unfortunately because i have reactive elements, my buttons are now flickering when the server is busy for a short period of time. I modified the code to utilize the setTimeout function to only lock the buttons after 1000 miliseconds but cant seem to get it to work. Can someone help me out?

Here is the new code:

```
function setBusy()
{
          if(!isBusy)
             return;

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
  
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
}

let isBusy = false;
$(document).on("shiny:busy", function() {
   isBusy = true;
   setTimeout(setBusy, 1000); // after one thousand milliseconds run the function above
});

$(document).on("shiny:idle", function() {
           isBusy = false; // if the setBusy fires after this, it'll see this and not set things to disabled
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
 
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = false;
}
});
```

Comment: Also getting this message in the Console: [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 148ms

Comment: I would try to put `isBusy` as an argument of the `setBusy` function. Because after 1000ms it is possible that `shiny:idle` has been triggered and then `setBusy` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, so the code is working, its disabling the buttons correctly during a long Shiny:busy period, but is happening immediately, not after the 1000 milliseconds like specified. Im wondering if i have written the setTimeout is not working correctly?

Comment: How should the disabling be triggered? After (a) certain button(s) has (have) been clicked? If this is the case I would put the disabling code in the click routine of these buttons (ideally even on the shiny side). Once the routine is finished you can enable them again.